# Sporadic Jar verifies through CMD but fails on launching JNLP file through JAVAWS

Tags: java, java-web-start, jar-signing

Occasional builds will fail to validate jars once I installed JRE 8u121

I sign my jars via the Ant command below:

```
<signjar
    jar="jsyntaxpane-0.9.5-b29.jar"
    keystore="keystorefile"
    alias="certificatealias"
    storepass="keystorepassword"
    tsaurl="http://timestamp.digicert.com"
    force="true"/>
```

The builds that throw unsigned jar errors are sporadic and the Jenkins execution of the Ant script shows Jar Signed.

In the environment attempting to run the jnlp file I the errors below.

JAVAWS Errors

Java Web Start Error:

Unsigned application requesting unrestricted access to system

Unsigned resource: jsyntaxpane-0.9.5-b29.jar
com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)

I get jar verified when using jarsigner to authenticate against both "http://timestamp.digicert.com" and the original keystore used to generate certs.

Comment: Is this issue only observed on 8u121? Was it working fine on previous versions like 8u111/8u112?

Comment: We just now observed it after updating to 8u121 but the last known working version was 8u101

Comment: Thanks, that seems strange. Is there any way to reproduce that at my end?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in Java which is tracked here - https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8173632